# TFS Release Management Web Deploy Task Error

Tags: tfs, web-deployment, webdeploy, tfs-2015

Hello everyone right now my team and me are trying to configure the release management solution within TFS 2015 version with the latest update we are getting the next error:

Deployment failed on machine 172.16.0.125 with following message :

System.Exception: An object at the specified path C:\Users\E2586~1.SAN does not exist.

7. 2016-09-09T19:32:22.8188676Z  ##[error]Deployment on one or more machines failed.
8. 2016-09-09T19:32:22.8188676Z ##[error]For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/iisextnreadme

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply an deploy failed error? Any other more detailed error information with the logs or deployed machine? Moreover, what's the detail version of your TFS 2015? This extension is supported in ***TFS 2015 Update 2*** onwards.

Comment: Hi, the version is TFS 2015 Update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this error occurs when the username of the domain, has a dot. I recommend that you create a username that you'd use just for tfs related tasks.